# Spring Boot can't find beans.xml in resources folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to display beans on view but it give exception.

Maven project structure:

[image: Key part of the structure]

Here is my code and I don't know why it can't find beans.xml

**Player class**

```
package kuraido.beansspring;

public class Player {

    String nickname;
    String level;
    public Player(String level, String nickname){
        this.level = level;
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Player's level and nick name: " + level + " " + nickname;
    }
}
```

**PlayerController Class(to display bean xml)**

```
package kuraido.beansspring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class PlayerController {
    static ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String peeji(){
        return context.getBean("player1").toString();
    }

}
```

**beans.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="player1" class="kuraido.beansspring.Player">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="99"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="N00bly"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="player2" class="kuraido.beansspring.Player">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="1"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="Garfunkel"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I haven't modified the generic Application class, it stayed untouched

**and here is the exception message:**

```
2022-03-26 00:16:26.463  INFO 6700 --- [           main] k.beansspring.BeansspringApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-26 00:16:27.165  INFO 6700 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-03-26 00:16:27.171  INFO 6700 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-03-26 00:16:27.171  INFO 6700 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
2022-03-26 00:16:27.253  INFO 6700 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-26 00:16:27.253  INFO 6700 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 739 ms
2022-03-26 00:16:27.288  WARN 6700 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'playerController' defined in file [C:\Users\Clyde\Desktop\Github\taihenJanai\assignment4\target\classes\kuraido\beansspring\PlayerController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2022-03-26 00:16:27.290  INFO 6700 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-03-26 00:16:27.299  INFO 6700 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-26 00:16:27.317 ERROR 6700 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'playerController' defined in file [C:\Users\Clyde\Desktop\Github\taihenJanai\assignment4\target\classes\kuraido\beansspring\PlayerController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at kuraido.beansspring.BeansspringApplication.main(BeansspringApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [C:\Users\Clyde\Desktop\Github\taihenJanai\assignment4\beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: beans.xml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:196) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:203) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:265) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:85) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at kuraido.beansspring.PlayerController.<clinit>(PlayerController.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: beans.xml
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:189) ~[spring-core-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    ... 38 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this  `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");` instead of this `ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");`

Comment: chen rahmat bratan

Comment: could you elaborate a little, like how FileSystem works and ClassPath doesn't